# Bootstrap, less, media-queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I use Twitter-Bootstrap & Jasny-Bootstrap and have the following media-queries:

```
// --- Media Queries (navmenu-main) ---
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        // Padding to move content beside "navmenu-main"
        padding: 0 0 0 300px;
    }

    .navmenu-main {
        // Remove Top-Padding from "navmenu-main" because it's only needed with "navbar-usage"
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}


// --- Media Queries (navbar-main) ---
@media (min-width: 1px) {
    .navbar-main .navbar-toggle {
        // Force to show toggle button
        display: block !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-main {
        // IE8 fix from "jasny-bootstrap" example 
        display: none !important; /* IE8 fix */
    }
}
```

So my Question is - do i have to place all Media-Queries at the end of the less-file or why do they work at the last position but not after the declarion of the classes used in them?

Comment: "at the end of the less-file" - no, there's no such requirement. "but not after the declarion" - hmm, can you provide an example of "non-working" code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a separate custom css file and link it to your index.html page. Put the link to the css after the ending style sheet of bootstrap in the index.html. Then in the file that you created put your custom media queries because the browser would read the custom style sheet last and get the info from there.

You should only used @media (min-width: 992px) {} once in your css and all you styles well be put there.

You can read more about media queries here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: "You should only used `@media (min-width: 992px) {}` *once*" - there's no such requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Breakpoints Like this:

```
@mobile:     ~"(max-width: 767px)";

@tablet:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)";

@desktop:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)";

@desktop-xl:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1350px)";
```